# How to create a class that holds collection of other class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a class called SchoolCatalog that will hold a collection of schools, e.g. Create an instance of SchoolCatalog for primary, middle, and high schools. (This is one of the problems from Code Academy Introduction To JavaScript). But, they have no proper guide on how to make a Catalog to hold all classes in the forum. So, if anybody can help me out I will be grateful.

```js
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name
    this._level = level
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents 
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
  
  get level() {
    return this._level
  }
  
  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents 
  }
  
  
  set numberOfStudents(studentsNumber) {
    if (typeof studentNumber === 'number')
      this._numberOfStudents = studentsNumber
    else
      console.log(`Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.`)
  }
  
  quickFacts() {
    console.log(`${this._name} educates ${this._numberOfStudents} students at the ${this._level} school level.`)
  }
  
  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {
    const randomTeacher = Math.floor(Math.random() * substituteTeachers.length)
    console.log(substituteTeachers[randomTeacher])
  }
  
}

// Primary School

class PrimarySchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, pickupPolicy) {
    super(name, 'primary', numberOfStudents)
    this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
  }
  
  get pickupPolicy() {
    return this._pickupPolicy
  }
}


class HighSchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, sportsTeams) {
    super(name,'high', numberOfStudents)
    this._sportsTeams = sportsTeams
  }
  
  get sportsTeams() {
    this._sportsTeams.forEach(team => {
      console.log(team)
    })
  }
}

const lorraineHansbury = new PrimarySchool('Lorraine Hansbury', 514, 'Students must be picked up by a parent, guardian, or a family member over the age of 13.')

lorraineHansbury.quickFacts()
PrimarySchool.pickSubstituteTeacher(['Jamal Crawford', 'Lou Williams', 'J. R. Smith', 'James Harden', 'Jason Terry', 'Manu Ginobli'])


const alSmith = new HighSchool('Al E. Smith', 415, ['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Volleyball', 'Track and Field'])
alSmith.sportsTeams


// My Attempt To Make Collection of Classes


/*class SchoolCatalog {
  constructor(schools) {
    this._schools = schools
  }
  
  get schools() {
    this._schools.forEach(school => {
      console.log(school)
    })
  }
}


const catalog = new SchoolCatalog([''])*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an issue with your implementation ?

```js
class Catalog{
   constructor(){
     this.schools = []
   }
   addSchool(school){
     if(!this[school._name]){
       // reference for easy access
       this[school._name]=school;
     }
     this.schools.push(school);
   }
}
```

If I needed a list I could iterate over and still easily get single schools from this is how i would do it ,

That said depending on your requirements this could be totally wrong.

Your implementation at first blush doesn't look to be incorrect , 
is it giving you a error?

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelRichardWalker. No, my code is not giving any error. I was making sure if the way I was solving was correct or not.

But can you please explain to me what you do in this part: 

`if(!this[school._name]){
       // reference for easy access
       this[school._name]=school;
     }`

Comment: My Catalog instance
`const catalog = new SchoolCatalog([lorraineHansbury, alSmith])`

With your `addSchool()` method
`const catalog = new SchoolCatalog()
catalog.addSchool(lorraineHansbury)`

Comment: Sure thing

Say i have `harvard` and `yale` in my catalog

if i wanted to access them 

all i'd have to do is is say catalog.harvard or catalog.yale and i would have access to the school

it just like saying 

```javascript

this.harvard =  harvard
```

but with square brackets `[ ]`

its called computed properties 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the exact same code exercice at CodeCademy and here is my answer to it:

```
class SchoolCatalog {
  constructor(){
    this._catalog = [];
  }

  get catalog(){
    return this._catalog;
  }

  addSchools(){
    if(!arguments.length){
      console.log('Invalid input: you must input a school')
    } else {
      for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        let level = arguments[i].level === 'primary' || arguments[i].level === 'middle' || arguments[i].level === 'high';
        level?this._catalog.push(arguments[i]):console.log(`The school "${arguments[i]}" is not a valid entry`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since all the school subsclasses have the property 'level' already set in the constructor, i validate the entry on the catalog by them. And i went a little bit further implementing a method on the school catalog to accept an undefined number of arguments to it, making the process of adding schools to the catalog a bit easier. You can also write your own addSchools() method with the rest operator! If you're a fellow codecademy student, you should try this :)